What is the etymology of 'ramshackle'? Looking for some clarity here
The online etymology seems unsatisfactory, particularly as the origin of 'shack' is so unclear. Are there any alternative opinions on the origin of this word?

Excellent question (most online sources say origin unknown). Which dictionaries have you seen? Links? Note that wiktionary is unreliable (ie sometimes it's great, but other times any ol' person just wrote any ol' thing).

There's no way to answer this without knowing which etymology you find unsatisfactory. Else any answer may just repeat what you've already rejected.

Please edit to tell what you found, so we can avoid duplicating it, or can challenge it. The first entries I find have nothing to do with "shack," but come from "ransack" where "sack" is related to "seek."

Merrian-Webster offers a plausible origin from Old Norse. Nothing to do with rams and shackles.

The word is an alteration of ransackled, an obsolete form of the verb ransack, meaning "to search through or plunder." (Ransack comes from Old Norse words meaning "house" and "seek.")
A home that has been ransacked has had its contents thrown into
disarray, and that image may be what inspired people to start using
ramshackle in the first half of the 19th century to describe something
that is poorly constructed or in a state of near collapse.
Ramshackle in modern use can also be figurative, as in "a ramshackle excuse for
the error”.

